# Alert email files older than 15 minutes in directory

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to send an email alert that looks at lastwritetime in a directory and anything older than 15 minutes send an email alert.  Here is my code and what I am trying to do.

```
        MailMessage CyclopsCentral = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        CyclopsCentral.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("shawn_swingler@cable.comcast.com");
        CyclopsCentral.To.Add("_spt-eqto-eng-eps_@comcast.com");
        CyclopsCentral.Subject = "Cyclops Central Not Updating";
        CyclopsCentral.Body = "Cyclops Central is not updating, please check the management center.";
        CyclopsCentral.Priority = MailPriority.High;


        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Users\!NCDSPOTVIEW\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\Chicago\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\");


            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("ScreenScrape.png");
                if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
                    fi.Send(CyclopsCentral);
            }
            //client.LogFileName = "d:\\smtp.txt";
            Console.WriteLine("Start to send email ...");
            //client.Send(CyclopsCentral);
            Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully");
        }

        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Does it throw an exception? Does it send emails to often? Does say it went fine but no email is received? (by the way, your line with "client.Send" is commented out)

Comment: You aren't using the output of Directory.GetFiles() (you are looping round the results but then not using the file in the code).

Comment: Also, you might want to remove your email addresses from your code for privacy reasons

Comment: What is `fi.Send(CyclopsCentral);` supposed to do? FileInfo.Send()? I think perhaps the `//client.Send(CyclopsCentral);` should be inside the foreach loop.

Comment: It is sending the email too often.  It needs to only send the email when the lastwritetime is more than 15 minutes.  Orgininally it was set to 1 hour.  I commented the line out because it sends an email when there is no issue.  Do not want to confuse.  fi.Send(CyclopsCentral) is supposed to send the email alert when the files lastwritetime is greater than 15 minutes.

Comment: Okay, so then post the custom extension method you wrote for the FileInfo method `.Send()` then.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the list of files that are returned from `Directory.GetFiles()`.  Try this instead:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
    if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15))
    {
        client.Send(CyclopsCentral);
    }
}
```

Also, if you only want 1 email regardless of the number of files it finds you may want to add a `break` statement after the `client.Send`.